# Format specifer in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

I'am trying to understand a C++ compiler behaviour. Here is a code, where I made two mistakes intentionally:

1. forgot `%ld` format specifier in `scanf` and just wrote `%`.
2. added unknown format specifer for `printf` - wrote `%l` instead of `%ld` for `long` datatype.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Complete the code.
    int a; long b; char c; float d; double e;
    scanf("%d % %c %f %lf", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    printf("%d \n%l \n%c \n%f \n%lf", a, b, c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

There is a snippet above, that successfully compiles and shows warnings. Why it didn't produce an error for unknown/missing C++ format specifier? How it was compiled?

Output:
[image: Input data and strange output after mistakes]

Comment: You should treat warnings as errors. They aren't to be ignored. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `%`  is not an unknown format specifier, but just that - a percent sign, followed by (one or more) white space. Your input stream is searched for a percent sign, and if none shows up as expected, it stops matching, and returns te number of already assigned fields - one.

Obviously, that is rarely what coders intent, so the compiler gives a warning about it. The way to state more clearly that you wanted a real percent sign would be to use `%%`. Percent and blank smells to the compiler as if you made an error, but it is not formally incorrect; therefore it is only a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is not required to tell you even that (be thankful it does!). Mismatch between format string and argument list is Undefined Behaviour.

Single `%` followed by space is an invalid specifier, which is also Undefined Behaviour.